# Order zero entire function.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

The order of an entire function $f$ is defined by the smallest $\alpha$ in $[0,\infty]$ such that $f(z)\ll e^{|z|^{\alpha+\epsilon}}$ for all $\epsilon>0$. An equivalent definition is, if $\limsup_{r\to\infty} {\frac{\log\log M(r,f)}{\log r}}=\lambda$, where $M(r,f)=\max|f(z)|$ on $|z|=r$, then $\lambda$ is the order of $f$.

**Question:** Let $f(z)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{z}{r_n})^2$ where $0<r_1<r_2<\ldots$. How to show that the order of this entire function is zero?

**My attempt:** From the first definition, I want to check that whether $\log\log |f(z)|$ grows slower than $\log{|z|^\epsilon}$ or not for all $\epsilon>0$. Now $\log\log |f(z)|=\log(\log|1+\frac{z}{r_1}|^2+ \log|1+\frac{z}{r_2}|^2+\cdots)=\log2+\log(\log|1+\frac{z}{r_1}|+ \log|1+\frac{z}{r_2}|+\cdots)$

From here I am not getting any clue to proceed. From the second definition I am not able to find the function $M(r,f)$.

Any suggestions or comments are welcome.

Comment: Note that the product won't converge for all choices of the $r_j$; I believe that the converence of the product is a necessary assumption for showing that the order is $0$.

Comment: Yes! may be it is required.

Comment: you need more conditions or maybe you need to show that the genus is zero (which is true) - $f(z)=\Pi (1+z/n^2)^2$ is given by an absolutely convergent product, and it has double roots at $-n^2$ with convergence exponent $1/2$ so it has genus zero and order $1/2$